# getDownloadURL takes some time

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I falling to get the url return by getDownloadURL appended on the ImageUrls state, getDownloadURL takes a second or two to return the url and it seems like the code continues running and doesn't wait for it to return the url

I am trying to upload multiple images and then create an object in firestore that has the images urls and description

```js
  const createAlbum = () => {
    addDoc(albumCollection, {
      name: albumName,
      category: category,
      images: imageUrls,
      description: description,
    });
  };

  const HandleUpload = (files) => {
    files.forEach((file) => {
      const storageRef = ref(
        storage,
        `/files/albums/${albumName}/${file.name}`
      );
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snap) => {},
        (err) => {},
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
            setImageUrls((prev) => [...prev, url]);
          });
        }
      );
    });
    createAlbum();

  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the download URL (like uploading the data, and most modern cloud APIs) is an asynchronous operation. While this call is being handled, your main code indeed continues to execute. Then when the download URL is available, your `then` callback is invoked with it, so you can use it.

For this reason, any code that needs the download URL needs to be **inside** the `then` callback, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized.

The simplest fix is to move `createAlbum` into the `then` callback:

```
uploadTask.on(
  "state_changed",
  (snap) => {},
  (err) => {},
  () => {
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
      setImageUrls((prev) => [...prev, url]);
      createAlbum();
    });
  }
);
```

If you only want to call `createAlbum()` once *all* uploads are completed, you can keep a counter or use `Promise.all()`:

```
const HandleUpload = (files) => {
  let promises = files.map((file) => {
    const storageRef = ref(
      storage,
      `/files/albums/${albumName}/${file.name}`
    );
    return uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file).then(() => {
      return getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
    });
  });
  Promise.all(promises).then((urls) => {
      setImageUrls(urls)
      createAlbum();
  })
};
```

This code uses the fact that the task returned by `uploadBytesResumable` is also a `Promise`, so we can use `then()` to know when it's completed, and then gets the download URL.

Note that if `setImageUrls` is a `useState` hook, that operation is asynchronous too. I recommend passing the image URLs to `createAlbum` explicitly, rather than trying to pass it through the state, so `createAlbum(urls)`

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use promise to error and callback to execute one time `createAlbum()`

like this:

```
uploadTask.on(
  "state_changed",
  (snap) => {},
  (err) => {},
  (),
        error => {
          console.log('upload error: ', error.message)
        },
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((url) => {
  setImageUrls((prev) => [...prev, url]);
  createAlbum();
});
        }
      )
```